# Get order data in custom checkout step

Tags: magento2, checkout-page

I've added one step in checkout after Review & payment step. Now i want to get last order id in this step. Can anyone help me?

Actually added the last step at the checkout page and that step I want to show just like checkout sucess page, but i dont know how to get the last order id at the my custom step in .html file

Comment: show us what you tried

Comment: last order id means previously placed order ID?

Comment: yes previously placed id

Answer (score 2):

```
   use Magento\Checkout\Model\Session as checkoutSession;

    /**
     * @var checkoutSession
     */
    private $checkoutSession;


    /**
     * @param checkoutSession $checkoutSession
     */
    public function __construct(
        checkoutSession $checkoutSession
    ) {
        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
    }
```

Now you can use like,

```
$previousOrderId = $this->checkoutSession->getLastOrderId();
```

Comment: this will display the entity_id which is quite useless for the customer.

Comment: Actually i get the orderId in js adn that id bind into .html dynamic

Comment: He did not mention which kind of id he wants @PhilippSander that's why I added `getLastOrderId()`

Comment: get the order id in JS means ? @RasikMiyani please update your exact requirenment otherwise someone will close your question ,

Comment: Actually added the last step at the checkout page and that step i want to show just like checkout sucess page, but i dont know how to get the last order id at the my custom step in .html file

Comment: @RasikMiyani use a block

Comment: but how to call daynamic block at  checkout step

Answer (score 0):

```
\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session::getLastRealOrder
```

this method does what you want on PHP side